# Why does the Tinker aspect only work on some skills?

Tags: dead-cells

The description for the Tinker aspect says "Reduce skill cooldown to 1 sec." In practice the cooldown seems to be unchanged on most abilities I've tried (Infantry Grenade, Pollo Power, Tonic, Face Flask). It does work as expected on the Sinew Slicer.

Why is the Tinker aspect reducing cooldown on some skills but not others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's badly worded, as confirmed by the wiki:

> Description incorrectly states that it reduces the cooldown for all skills.

According to [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/588650/discussions/0/3196993316895591662/) and other Reddit users it only works with [Deployables](https://deadcells.fandom.com/wiki/Deployable_Traps).